# Way display:table doesn't act like regular table?

Tags: css

You can see in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/noamway/AVwsP/

```
    <div style="width: 100%; display: table; border: 1px solid black;">
        Hello
    </div>
    <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

That they are the same but the border make the different.

Any solution to that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I get the question..

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing:border-box` to the div so that the borders are rendered within the box as apposed to outside.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/AVwsP/28/)**

Answer (score -1):

how about this,

```
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        Hello
    </div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]